# Issues with a Query within the main Query using DatabaseDotcom Ruby gem

Tags: salesforce-id, sobject, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm having a issue with pulling the data out of what would be a array of object data in my SFDC query. Im using the `databasedotcom` gem.

### Code

```
def self.data_query

 #@client is defined at a class level

 name = "Bob Jones INC"
 query_str = "SELECT Id, CaseNumber, (SELECT Id, Part_Number__c FROM Serial_Numbers__r) FROM Case WHERE Company ='#{name}'"
 result = @client.query(query_str)

 returned_data = result.first

 #Make Some Variables
 $_ID = returned_data.Id
 $_CASENUMBER = returned_data.CaseNumber

 # Now there is multiple Serial_Numbers__r, how can i capture them (id and Part Number)
 # I was thinking something like this, but it doesnt work. returns error about serial_numbers__r

 $_ARRAY = []     

 returned_data.Serial_Numbers__r do { |x|
     $_ARRAY << { serial_id => x.Id, serial_partnum => x.Part_Number__c}
 }
 end

 response = "Data is equals #{$_ID}, #{$_CASENUMBER} and Array #{$_ARRAY.each}"

end #data_query
```

....

```
puts "begin"
data_query
```

Currently this causing a `NoMethod` error on Serial_Numbers__r on the returned_data object

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you liked queries, so I put a query in your query so you can query while you query. (Couldn't resist.)

Comment: hahaha @DavidSchach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of support for relationships appears to be an open issue [Nested Associations/Relationships that is Array-based](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/58). A couple of forks are mentioned that perhaps you could use.

(No commits to the project in the last year - not encouraging.)

From [Accessing Salesforce Data from Ruby](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Accessing_Salesforce_Data_From_Ruby):

> One of the most important gem limitations is a lack of support for
>   relationships — no belongs_to, has_many, and so forth. Handling
>   relationships yourself isn't as much of a burden as you might expect
>   because relationships between Salesforce objects are typically much
>   simpler than you're used to in traditional RDBMS schemas. The
>   Salesforce query language, SOQL, is designed to solve a well-defined
>   and restricted set of problems, and to keep things running smoothly in
>   Salesforce's shared cloud.